# How do I find a the row with an attribute that occurs the most?

Tags: sql, count, max

I have a table that has vehicle make, service_name and I need to find the most occurring vehicle make. I have a query that works but I would like to know if there's an easier way to get the same result without creating a new table.
Here's my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT vehicle_make, COUNT(service_name) as num_of_services
FROM StartingTable
GROUP BY vehicle_make)
WHERE num_of_services = (SELECT MAX(num_of_services FROM  (SELECT vehicle_make, COUNT(service_name) as num_of_services
FROM StartingTable
GROUP BY vehicle_make))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do the following:

```
SELECT vehicle_make, num_of_services 
FROM (SELECT vehicle_make, COUNT(service_name) as num_of_services,
             max(COUNT(service_name)) over () as max_num_of_services
      FROM StartingTable
      GROUP BY vehicle_make
     ) st
WHERE num_of_services = max_num_of_services;
```

This uses a window function to calculate the maximum.  Mixing aggregation and window functions looks a bit strange at first, but this calculates the maximum of the count -- which is exactly what you are looking for.

EDIT:

Another way to do this is perhaps even simpler, if you only want one row:

```
SELECT top 1 vehicle_make, COUNT(service_name) as num_of_services
FROM StartingTable
GROUP BY vehicle_make
ORDER BY COUNT(service_name) desc
```